# DataGrid DataTable binding - Get selected DataTable row index

Tags: c#, binding, datagrid, datatable, indexing

I've got a DataTable bound to a DataGrid in WPF. Let's say this DataTable is populated with following:

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║  Header1   ║  Header2   ║  Header3   ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ Something1 ║ Something2 ║ Something3 ║
║ Something4 ║ Something5 ║ Something6 ║
║ Something7 ║ Something8 ║ Something9 ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

The code would be following:

```
DataTable dtTest = new DataTable();
dtTest.Columns.Add("Header1", typeof(string));
dtTest.Columns.Add("Header2", typeof(string));
dtTest.Columns.Add("Header3", typeof(string));

dtTest.Rows.Add("Something1", "Something2", "Something3");
dtTest.Rows.Add("Something4", "Something5", "Something6");
dtTest.Rows.Add("Something7", "Something8", "Something9");

// Bind to DataGrid
datagrid.DataContext = dtTest.DefaultView;
```

My question is, **how do I get a list of selected row indexes of the *DataTable*** as the user starts selecting rows through the DataGrid? A list of selected row indexes of the *DataGrid* itself would be useless, as sorting of a specific column would change the indexes.

### Answer by Dennis

```
List<int> SelectedIndexes = dataGrid
                              .SelectedItems
                              .Cast<DataRowView>()
                              .Select(view => dataTable.Rows.IndexOf(view.Row))
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: Dude, I love how you built that screenshot with "═" ASCII characters. Reminds me of my QuickBasic days...

Comment: Which, if any, of those columns contain unique values (or is some combination of those columns a unique value)?

Comment: If they did, I could do it with LINQ. But sadly they don't.

Comment: Don't you want to set the datagrid's `ItemsSource`, not the `DataContext`?

Comment: My DataGrid's columns are bound to specific columms in XAML (e.g. `Binding="{Binding ID}"`) already, so setting the DataContext should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
dataGrid
  .SelectedItems
  .Cast<DataRowView>()
  .Select(view => dataTable.Rows.IndexOf(view.Row));
```

Comment: This triggers an InvalidCastException, as I can't cast a DataGrid's `DataRowView` to a DataTable's `DataRow`.

Answer (score 0):

From [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/119505/Get-Selected-items-in-a-WPF-datagrid):

```
private void btnProcessMedia_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (dgProjects.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < dgProjects.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
      System.Data.DataRowView selectedFile = (System.Data.DataRowView)dgProjects.SelectedItems[i];
      string str = Convert.ToString(selectedFile.Row.ItemArray[10]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to to get the selected indexes of the DataTable, not the DataGrid. (DataGrid's sorting will move indexes)

Comment: Could you not just populate the grid with a hidden key value and use that instead? Or use .selectedIndex and dissable the users ability to re order rows?